# Does lldb have a comm command like gdb?

Tags: gdb, lldb

In GDB, we can do

```
comm 1
p x
end
```

This prints x whenever the breakpoint 1 is hit. Can lldb do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  See:

(lldb) help breakpoint command add